# default validation in jqxGrid

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I am using custom validation in jqxGrid column. 
After the cell value does not  satisfies the custom validation , I get custom message but when I enter correct value I get default validation message : 
"Entered value is not valid"

```
validation : function (cell,value) {
        var reg = /^\s*\d+\s*$/ig;
        if ( !reg.test(value)) {
        return {result:false , message: "Positive numbers only allowed "};
         }                  
        }
```

Please see fiddle link here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/0u7n0ymg/9/). I have added validation on Quantity column of Grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing on return true in validation fn
return true should be returned from validation function if regex is successful.

```
>validation : function (cell,value) {
        var reg = /^\s*\d+\s*$/ig;
        if ( !reg.test(value)) {
        return {result:false , message: "Positive numbers only allowed "};
         }    
        return true;              
        }
```

So now default message would be gone.